# socat is exiting on signal 11

Tags: segmentation-fault, socat

I'va faced with pretty strange problem, socat without any reasons just get segfaulted and I don't know what to do to debug the things out. Complete log:

```
2015/08/27 16:55:58 socat[1] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:8080
2015/08/27 16:55:59 socat[1] N accepting connection from AF=2 10.116.176.1:53363 on AF=2 10.116.176.6:8080
2015/08/27 16:55:59 socat[1] N forked off child process 9
2015/08/27 16:55:59 socat[1] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:8080
2015/08/27 16:55:59 socat[9] N opening connection to AF=2 10.116.1.191:8080
2015/08/27 16:55:59 socat[9] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 10.116.176.6:52167
2015/08/27 16:55:59 socat[9] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [5,5]
2015/08/27 16:55:59 socat[9] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:55:59 socat[9] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:55:59 socat[9] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:55:59 socat[9] N exiting with status 0
2015/08/27 16:55:59 socat[1] N childdied(): handling signal 17
2015/08/27 16:56:04 socat[1] N accepting connection from AF=2 10.116.176.1:53367 on AF=2 10.116.176.6:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:04 socat[1] N forked off child process 10
2015/08/27 16:56:04 socat[1] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:04 socat[10] N opening connection to AF=2 10.116.1.191:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:04 socat[10] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 10.116.176.6:52171
2015/08/27 16:56:04 socat[10] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [5,5]
2015/08/27 16:56:04 socat[10] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:04 socat[10] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:04 socat[10] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:04 socat[10] N exiting with status 0
2015/08/27 16:56:04 socat[1] N childdied(): handling signal 17
2015/08/27 16:56:09 socat[1] N accepting connection from AF=2 10.116.176.1:53370 on AF=2 10.116.176.6:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:09 socat[1] N forked off child process 11
2015/08/27 16:56:09 socat[1] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:09 socat[11] N opening connection to AF=2 10.116.1.191:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:09 socat[11] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 10.116.176.6:52174
2015/08/27 16:56:09 socat[11] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [5,5]
2015/08/27 16:56:09 socat[11] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:09 socat[11] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:09 socat[11] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:09 socat[11] N exiting with status 0
2015/08/27 16:56:09 socat[1] N childdied(): handling signal 17
2015/08/27 16:56:14 socat[1] N accepting connection from AF=2 10.116.176.1:53373 on AF=2 10.116.176.6:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:14 socat[1] N forked off child process 12
2015/08/27 16:56:14 socat[1] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:14 socat[12] N opening connection to AF=2 10.116.1.191:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:14 socat[12] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 10.116.176.6:52177
2015/08/27 16:56:14 socat[12] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [5,5]
2015/08/27 16:56:14 socat[12] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:14 socat[12] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:14 socat[12] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:14 socat[12] N exiting with status 0
2015/08/27 16:56:14 socat[1] N childdied(): handling signal 17
2015/08/27 16:56:19 socat[1] N accepting connection from AF=2 10.116.176.1:53377 on AF=2 10.116.176.6:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:19 socat[1] N forked off child process 13
2015/08/27 16:56:19 socat[1] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:19 socat[13] N opening connection to AF=2 10.116.1.191:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:19 socat[13] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 10.116.176.6:52181
2015/08/27 16:56:19 socat[13] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [5,5]
2015/08/27 16:56:19 socat[13] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:19 socat[13] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:19 socat[13] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:19 socat[13] N exiting with status 0
2015/08/27 16:56:19 socat[1] N childdied(): handling signal 17
2015/08/27 16:56:24 socat[1] N accepting connection from AF=2 10.116.176.1:53380 on AF=2 10.116.176.6:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:24 socat[1] N forked off child process 14
2015/08/27 16:56:24 socat[1] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:29 socat[1] N accepting connection from AF=2 10.116.176.1:53382 on AF=2 10.116.176.6:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:29 socat[1] N forked off child process 15
2015/08/27 16:56:29 socat[1] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:29 socat[15] N opening connection to AF=2 10.116.1.191:8080
2015/08/27 16:56:29 socat[15] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 10.116.176.6:52186
2015/08/27 16:56:29 socat[15] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [5,5]
2015/08/27 16:56:29 socat[15] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:29 socat[15] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:29 socat[15] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF
2015/08/27 16:56:29 socat[15] N exiting with status 0
2015/08/27 16:56:29 socat[1] N childdied(): handling signal 17
2015/08/27 16:56:33 socat[1] N socat_signal(): handling signal 11
2015/08/27 16:56:33 socat[1] E exiting on signal 11
2015/08/27 16:56:33 socat[1] N exit(139
```

what I'm doing is following:

```
socat -x -v -d -d TCP-LISTEN:8080,reuseaddr,fork TCP:dnsname.of.the service:8080
```

socat version is:

```
/ # socat -V
socat by Gerhard Rieger - see www.dest-unreach.org
socat version 1.7.3.0 on Jun 16 2015 07:12:18
   running on Linux version #21-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 14 18:31:11 UTC 2015, release 3.19.0-21-generic, machine x86_64
features:
  #define WITH_STDIO 1
  #define WITH_FDNUM 1
  #define WITH_FILE 1
  #define WITH_CREAT 1
  #define WITH_GOPEN 1
  #define WITH_TERMIOS 1
  #define WITH_PIPE 1
  #define WITH_UNIX 1
  #define WITH_ABSTRACT_UNIXSOCKET 1
  #define WITH_IP4 1
  #define WITH_IP6 1
  #define WITH_RAWIP 1
  #define WITH_GENERICSOCKET 1
  #define WITH_INTERFACE 1
  #define WITH_TCP 1
  #define WITH_UDP 1
  #define WITH_SCTP 1
  #define WITH_LISTEN 1
  #define WITH_SOCKS4 1
  #define WITH_SOCKS4A 1
  #define WITH_PROXY 1
  #define WITH_SYSTEM 1
  #define WITH_EXEC 1
  #undef WITH_READLINE
  #define WITH_TUN 1
  #define WITH_PTY 1
  #undef WITH_OPENSSL
  #undef WITH_FIPS
  #undef WITH_LIBWRAP
  #define WITH_SYCLS 1
  #define WITH_FILAN 1
  #define WITH_RETRY 1
  #define WITH_MSGLEVEL 0 /*debug*/
```

any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem, well not quite

```
2016/06/18 11:49:19 socat[19744] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:25560
2016/06/18 11:49:23 socat[19744] N accepting connection from AF=2 127.0.0.1:53358 on AF=2 127.0.0.1:25560
2016/06/18 11:49:23 socat[19744] N forked off child process 19746
2016/06/18 11:49:23 socat[19744] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:25560
2016/06/18 11:49:23 socat[19744] N socat_signal(): handling signal 11
2016/06/18 11:49:23 socat[19744] E exiting on signal 11
2016/06/18 11:49:23 socat[19744] N exit(139)
```

I think socat does not like doing dns resolution, i have no clue how this crashes it, but if i do the same setup without fork, then socat gets stuck and cant respond to signals anymore

I would `ping {the server}` and take the ip that is in the brackets

```
64 bytes from hosted-by.reliablesite.net (104.243.34.98):
                                          ^^ use the ip instead
```

If you can use the ip instead then it will work.